# Can't solve the Javascript error

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing a code in which if we hover over the pictures they will be seen in the div tag and also their alt text instead of the tag in div.
The HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Photo Gallery</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gallery.css">
<script src = "js/gallery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "image">
    Hover over an image below to display here.
</div>

<img class = "preview" alt = "Styling with a Bandana" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">

<img class = "preview" alt = "With My Boy" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">

<img class = "preview" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt = "Young Puppy" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">

</body>
</html>
```

> Here is the CSS code:

```
body{
    margin: 2%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #b3b3b3;
}
#image{
line-height:650px;
    width: 575px;
height: 650px;
    border:5px solid black;
    margin:0 auto;
background-color: #8e68ff;
background-image: url('');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
color:#FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
background-size: 100%;
margin-bottom:25px;
font-size: 150%;
}
.preview{
    width:10%;
    margin-left:17%;
border: 10px solid black;
}
img{
    width:95%;
}
```

> The Javascript code is:

```
function upDate(previewPic){
/* In this function you should 
1) change the url for the background image of the div with the id =    "image" 
to the source file of the preview image

2) Change the text  of the div with the id = "image" 
to the alt text of the preview image 
*/
var urlString = 'url(previewPic.src)';
document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = urlString;
document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = previewPic.alt;

}

function unDo(){
 /* In this function you should 
 1) Update the url for the background image of the div with the id = "image" 
 back to the orginal-image.  You can use the css code to see what that  original URL was

2) Change the text  of the div with the id = "image" 
back to the original text.  You can use the html code to see what that    original text was
*/
var urlString = 'url(image)';
document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = urlString;
document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = image.div;
}
```

I have to only know what's wrong with my Javascript code.I have used the debugger already and it's showing errors yet I cannot understand how to solve them.

All the things that need to be done has been given in the comments.When I hover over the picture the text inside the div is updated but it doesn't get undone when I hover outside the picture.And the picture doesn't get updated and undone.So if I could get any help.

Comment: What are the errors you get?

Comment: File not found error.

Comment: Are you sure  about this?: `'url(previewPic.src)';`

Comment: Then I guess it can't find the file.

Comment: Try visiting the locations you specify in your code manually, make sure that they do, in fact, exist.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez..No actually I am not sure of that.But I thought that it would work like that.can you please tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: Just a guess. Permissions issue?

Comment: @BrandonAnzaldi..So what are you suggesting..actually I want the src file and I have passed previewPic as a parameter.That's why I used previewPic.src but it isn't working.

Comment: @RahulSingh Ah! Therein lies your problem. It's actually trying to fetch, very literally, `previewPic.src`, not the value assigned to that property. In order to do that, it'll need to be something like this: (As Steve mentioned in a comment below) `"url(" + previewPic.src + ")"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're not escaping your variables. Your progmatically generated CSS has the literal value of `url(previewPic.src)`, which tries to find the nonexistent `previewPic.src` file on your server. Instead, you need to concatenate the strings with the variable.

```
var urlString = 'url(' + previewPic.src + ')';
```

Or, another possibility, depending on how important [browser compatibility](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-template_literals_basic_functionality) is to you, you could use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead.

```
var urlString = `url(${previewPic.src})`;
```

Note the backticks, and the escape sequence of `${}` with in the template literal.

To get the original text back, you can't call on the original element, since the text is overwritten when you set the innerHTML on it.

Instead, just reset the innerHTML to the value you gave it initially in the HTML.

```js
function upDate(previewPic){
/* In this function you should 
1) change the url for the background image of the div with the id =    "image" 
to the source file of the preview image

2) Change the text  of the div with the id = "image" 
to the alt text of the preview image 
*/
var urlString = 'url(' + previewPic.src + ')';
document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = urlString;
document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = previewPic.alt;

}

function unDo(){
 /* In this function you should 
 1) Update the url for the background image of the div with the id = "image" 
 back to the orginal-image.  You can use the css code to see what that  original URL was

2) Change the text  of the div with the id = "image" 
back to the original text.  You can use the html code to see what that    original text was
*/
var urlString = 'none';
document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = urlString;
document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = 'Hover over an image below to display here.';
}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 2%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #b3b3b3;
}
#image{
line-height:650px;
    width: 575px;
height: 650px;
    border:5px solid black;
    margin:0 auto;
background-color: #8e68ff;
background-image: url('');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
color:#FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
background-size: 100%;
margin-bottom:25px;
font-size: 150%;
}
.preview{
    width:10%;
    margin-left:17%;
border: 10px solid black;
}
img{
    width:95%;
}
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Photo Gallery</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gallery.css">
<script src = "js/gallery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "image">
    Hover over an image below to display here.
</div>

<img class = "preview" alt = "Styling with a Bandana" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">

<img class = "preview" alt = "With My Boy" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">

<img class = "preview" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt = "Young Puppy" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Everything works fine except the last code to change the code back to what's written in the div.When I hover outside the pictures it;s saying undefined.

Comment: Ok..means you ar suggesting to write the line itself.I thought there was some other process also..Thanks..:)

Comment: @RahulSingh There is, when the element hasn't been overwritten. In your original code, `image`, wasn't defined, and if it were set to the element selector, it is itself a reference to a div. It doesn't have a property called div. Glad I was able to help! Happy coding!

Comment: Yeah..Thanks Brandon.:)

Answer (score 2):

Here you have the image and alt text swiching effect on mouseover... And the original content back on mouse out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Photo Gallery</title>
    <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gallery.css"-->
    <!--script src = "js/gallery.js"--></script>
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 2%;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background-color: #b3b3b3;
        }
        #image{
        line-height:650px;
            width: 575px;
        height: 650px;
            border:5px solid black;
            margin:0 auto;
        background-color: #8e68ff;
        background-image: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/8700/wall-animal-dog-pet.jpg'); /* Original image was missing */
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        text-align: center;
        background-size: 100%;
        margin-bottom:25px;
        font-size: 150%;
        }
        .preview{
            width:10%;
            margin-left:17%;
        border: 10px solid black;
        }
        img{
            width:95%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "image">
        Hover over an image below to display here.
    </div>

    <img class = "preview" alt = "Styling with a Bandana" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">

    <img class = "preview" alt = "With My Boy" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">

    <img class = "preview" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt = "Young Puppy" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">
    <script>
        function upDate(previewPic){
            var urlString = 'url('+previewPic.src+')';
            document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = urlString;
            document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = previewPic.alt;
        }

        function unDo(){
            var urlString = "url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/8700/wall-animal-dog-pet.jpg')";
            document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = urlString;
            document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "Hover over an image below to display here.";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Louys..Thank you very much.Brandon above told me about the quotes but I cannot understand in the url why are you concatenating them as strings?

Comment: Because it is a CSS value that need to be formated like this. Read on here : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Comment: Ok means background-image and backgroundImage are the same thing you are suggesting?right?

Comment: Yes background-image is the CSS property name and backgroundImage is the javascript property that refers to the CSS property of the object it is attached to.

Comment: Learning javascript implies learning other languages too... Since javascript interacts with them. This is often confusing because of the similar names... But with time, you'll get the naming structure difference.

Comment: One last thing.so couldn't have we just written..url("previewPic.src").instead of "url( "+ previewPic.src+")".means the concatenation thing it isn't mentioned in the post that's why I am getting a little confused here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111820/discussion-between-louys-patrice-bessette-and-rahul-singh).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with
`var urlString = 'url(previewPic.src)';` & `var urlString = 'url(image)';`

If I am not wrong the it has to be like this

```
var urlString = "url('previewPic.src')" // Note the quotes
```

Check [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp) for more information

Comment: Having a url() without quotes in CSS is perfectly acceptable. Perhaps not standards compliant, but every major browser I've seen works without quotes. Also, W3Schools DOES NOT equal the W3C. The W3C is a working group, W3Schools is a learning site with a [somewhat checkered past](http://www.w3fools.com). In fact, this conflation between the two name-wise is part of what irked so many people about W3Schools.

Comment: It probably needs to be `'url(" + previewPic.src + ")'`

Comment: @BrandonAnzaldi you are right

Comment: @Steve Just a heads up, your quotes are mismatched. It will be a string with the value `url(" + previewPic.src + ")`

Comment: @BrandonAnzaldi ah, thought I fixed that, but I just reversed them! Quite right, both sets of quotes need to be the same.

Comment: Ok..it works now..Thanks Brandon and Steve.One problem that is even now..That I can't make the text undone when I am hovering outside the pictures.It's showing [objectHTMLDivelement] .So what is wrong in my last code.Should I write the code directly which I have written in the div?Or is there any other process

Comment: A simple thought I have reading this: The most efficient homework are the ones you really worked on.

Comment: @Yeah and they are efficient beacuse when you are working on a single problem for two days and can't get them and you ask some experts and they tell you in extra details from which you learn many thing.:)

Comment: You really worked 2 days without removing the teacher's comments and not setting an url for the original image in the CSS ???

Comment: Haha..No the teacher didn't give me the Javascript code and I have started it just a few days ago.And I didn't delete the comment so that if I ask any question the person don't have to think of what I am trying to get from the code.Simple as that.And pardon me but I am not a good coder as of you.That's why I ask such easy questions.:)